# Imposing similar heights for boxes using \parbox

Tags: beamer, boxes, parbox

I am trying to impose similar heights for 2 different boxes. I am trying to use \parbox but this doesn't work very well since the boxes have still different heights :

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{fancybox}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
    \begin{equation*}
\ovalbox{\parbox[b][0.75\baselineskip]{0.5\linewidth}{$\nabla \zeta_0 = -\frac{\delta r}{h^{*}}  \ \text{avec :}\ \frac{1}{h^{*}} = \frac{1}{\alpha h_p} - \frac{1}{H}$}
}
\
\ovalbox{\parbox[b][0.75\baselineskip]{0.5\linewidth}{$\alpha = 1 - \frac{n}{n'} \ \text{et :} \ h_p = h_0$}
}
    \end{equation*}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

What am I missing here ?

[image]

Thank you in advance,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Adaptations

- Replace position `b` (bottom) by `c` (center)
- increased height a little bit (using 1 `\baselineskip`)

#### Result

[image]

#### Code

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{fancybox}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
    \begin{equation*}
\ovalbox{\parbox[c][\baselineskip]{0.5\linewidth}{$\nabla \zeta_0 = -\frac{\delta r}{h^{*}}  \ \text{avec :}\ \frac{1}{h^{*}} = \frac{1}{\alpha h_p} - \frac{1}{H}$}
}
\
\ovalbox{\parbox[c][\baselineskip]{0.5\linewidth}{$\alpha = 1 - \frac{n}{n'} \ \text{et :} \ h_p = h_0$}
}
    \end{equation*}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

As already said for your previous question, `hf-tikz` is more powerful, including options to specify the height:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage[beamer,customcolors,nofill]{hf-tikz}
\hfsetbordercolor{black}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
    \begin{equation*}
    \tikzmarkin<1->{a}(0.1,-0.4)(-0.1,0.6) 
    \nabla \zeta_0 = -\frac{\delta r}{h^{*}}  \ \text{avec :}\ \frac{1}{h^{*}} = \frac{1}{\alpha h_p} - \frac{1}{H} 
    \tikzmarkend{a}
    \quad
    \tikzmarkin<1->{b}(0.1,-0.4)(-0.1,0.6) 
    \alpha = 1 - \frac{n}{n'} \ \text{et :} \ h_p = h_0
    \tikzmarkend{b}
    \end{equation*}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @Wiss I think using this approach would be better as the suggested package [hf-tikz](https://ftp.gwdg.de/pub/ctan/graphics/pgf/contrib/hf-tikz/hf-tikz.pdf) is made for your use case and you don't have to set a width manually.